# CSS attribute selector + after: Not Working in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I have the following css/html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a[href$=".pdf"]:after{
            content: "[pdf]";

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is an example <a href="helloworld.pdf">Text with a pdf link</a></p>
<p>This is an example <a href="helloworld.png">Non PDF link</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I open this in **IE8**, it works as expected: the PDF link gets text added after, and the PNG does not.  When I open it in **Chrome 23.0.1271.97** however, both links get [pdf] appended to the end.  Even stranger, when I click on the non-pdf link, the [pdf] at the end goes away while clicking, while it does not disappear when clicking on the PDF link.

[image: see what the Chrome result looks like here]

when I do

```
a[href$=".pdf"]{
    color: red;
}
```

the pdf link is red while the non-pdf one isn't, even in Chrome.

Why does Chrome seem to not respect the attribute selector when using :after and content?

Comment: `href$=` matches the end of the href attribute, so it only matches urls that end in .pdf

Comment: That for making sure .pdf is at the end of the statement, though I've never seen it used in css before. I've had Chrome issues using the nth-child class so I am not surprised it has issues with this one. Your code seems legit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I have a [fiddle with just the :after rule](http://jsfiddle.net/Bbv5B/1/), I see the same issue.

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:after{
    content: "[pdf]";
}
```

However when I [add the rule without :after](http://jsfiddle.net/Bbv5B/2/), the [pdf] is no longer on the bottom one. Strange indeed.

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:after{
    content: "[pdf]";
}

a[href$=".pdf"]{
    color: red;
}
```

It seems like this may be a [chrome bug](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/7fPyT-A7RTI). :before/:after don't work with attribute selectors unless the item is already styled with an attribute selector. [Here's the logged bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125719#c10).

Comment: Agree, I came to the same conclusion. Introduction of a straight call seems to correct it.

Comment: I was worried it might be a Chrome/Webkit bug, looks like the underlying bug has been fixed though.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems to be a bug. I does seem, however, that one work around is to set *something* using the base selector, then set the after. So for instance, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/vGMPr/3/):

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  font-size: inherit;
}
a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
  content: "[pdf]";
}
```